# Google Plus button not showing: FireBug shows a "NetworkError: 404 not found"

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus, social-media

I want to show a Google Plus (Google+) button on my website. On my page I have:

```
<g:plusone size="tall"></g:plusone>
```

As a script, below on the same page, I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/static/external/google/plusone.js">
        { lang: 'da' }
    </script>
```

I made sure the script is up to date, and even tried Googles CDN, but still no button is shown.

In FireBug, I can see I get the following error, which probably is the error:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://plus.google.com/_/apps-static/_/js/gapi/gcm_ppb,googleapis_client,plusone/rt=j/ver=tfhAJ-U7Vlc.da./sv=1/am=!brN6X75-Zu-IDRYPeA/d=1/cb=gapi.loaded0"
```

This is a problem both locally and online on my production site.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code instead :

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="inline" data-width="300"></div>
```

Javascript :

```
window.___gcfg = {lang: 'da'};

(function() {
   var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
   po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
```

Result : http://jsfiddle.net/L3XR7/